# SSL, Connection is not secure

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I'm using https://letsencrypt.org Cert for my web. Last thing i made yesterday is to set the cert and polish nginx config.

Before i went to sleep everything was great, my Connection was secured, the "locker" near address bar was green, it said SSL by Eset.

Today after i woke up it says "Connection is not secure", please have a loot at https://extrasalty.eu

nginx config for the web:

```
# cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/extrasalty.eu
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    extrasalty.eu;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/extrasalty.eu/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/extrasalty.eu/privkey.pem;

        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen  443 ssl default_server;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
(...)
```

Edit:

It seems it's being "verified" and ssl cert is showing up as secure when i log in to the forums, but before that it says "Not secure", any clue why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the "Sign in through STEAM" image and google-font are loaded via http.

Here's the copy as curl of it: curl 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_large_noborder.png' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'If-None-Match: "16e5-4d62d40919e00"' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Wed, 20 Feb 2013 19:49:12 GMT' --compressed

Serve it via https and the error will be gone.
Basically, change the src in the img tag to https and also, load the google-font via https. Give it a try.

Comment: Errors: 

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://extrasalty.eu/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,200italic,400italic,600italic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. <br>


(index):159 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://extrasalty.eu/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_large_noborder.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

Your site uses resources that are included via plain HTTP, resulting in a [mixed-content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content?hl=en) warning.

When you click the SSL icon in Chrome, you can see the following information:

[image]

Following the link below and reloading the page show that the following file is included:

```
<img src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_large_noborder.png" alt="Logowanie za pomocą platformy steam">
```

Comment: Thanks @RaviTezu, i fixed my issues with the ssl, thanks StephenKing for the update as well. I have question regarding posts content. What if someone will upload image to the post which will be on http, not on https (using some external mirror). SSL warning will be prompted about that, right?

Comment: Until you serve all the content(hosted on your server) via https, there won't be any errors. I think, users uploading the images via http is a different problem and I think, you are the one who controls it. I don't have much info. about it. Sorry!

Comment: How the upload is done does not matter at all for the users downloading these files. But if your site runs with SSL, the user would receive a warning during upload, if the form's action would use plain text HTTP (`<form action="http://..." />`). So this shouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: May 2023: had the same issue using Nginx on Ubuntu 22.* setup. This was the answer - make sure proxy is enabled on your DNS hosting site (e.g., cloudflare)